# Spark Streaming - Jobs run concurrently with default spark.streaming.concurrentJobs setting

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have come across a wierd behaviour in Spark Streaming Job.
We have used the default value for spark.streaming.concurrentJobs which is 1.
The same streaming job was running for more than a day properly with the batch interval being set to 10 Minutes.
Suddenly that same job has started running concurrently for all the batches that come in without putting them in Queue.

Has anyone faced this before? 
This would be of great help!

Comment: Is 10 mins interval sufficient to complete single job? how much time requried to complete single job.

Comment: Yes! One Job gets completed in 5 to 6 Minutes. Even if not, the other jobs should only be in QUEUED status and not in PROCESSING status.

Comment: Are you running your Spark job on YARN?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of behavior seems to be curious but I believe seems to happen when there is only 1 job running at a time and if batch processing time < batch interval, then the system seems to be stable.

Spark Streaming creator Tathagata hs mentioned about this: [How jobs are assigned to executors in Spark Streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528006/how-jobs-are-assigned-to-executors-in-spark-streaming).