# spark streaming processing parallelism

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I use a spark streaming job to process my input request.

My spark input takes a filename, downloads the data, make some changes and sends the data to downstream.

Currently, it takes 2 mins to process one single file.

These file requests are independent operation and can be tasked parallel.

Currently, when I give my input through netcat server, each request is processed first and then next request is processed. I want this operation to be parallel.

```
@timing
def sleep_func(data):
    print("start file processing")            
    time.sleep(60)      
    print("end file processing")                  
    return data

rdd = ssc.socketTextStream(sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]))     
rdd = rdd.map(sleep_func)    
final_rects = rdd.pprint()
```

Im trying  to create multiple sockettextstream that will be processed in each executor based on this.

```
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/streaming-programming-guide.html#level-of-parallelism-in-data-receiving

rdd = [ssc.socketTextStream(sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2])) for _ in range(5)]
```

but not sure how to process these individual streams separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean you want to process batch of data parallel instead of one by one, right?

see: [How jobs are assigned to executors in Spark Streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528006/how-jobs-are-assigned-to-executors-in-spark-streaming)