# Reading Multiple kafka topics through spark structure is not working?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to read data from multiple kafka topic by using structure streaming.
Version 
kafka - 2.12-1.0.0
Spark Structure Streaming - 2.2.1

My code :-

```
val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("StreamLocallyExample")
      .config("spark.master", "local")
       .config("spark.sql.streaming.checkpointLocation", "path/XXYY")
       .getOrCreate()

    val kafkaStreamDF = sparkSession.readStream.format("kafka")
          .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
          .option("subscribe", "test,trial")
          .load()

    val df=kafkaStreamDF.selectExpr("CAST(value AS string)")

    val query=df.writeStream .outputMode("append")
                .format("console")
                .option("truncate","false")
                .start()

    query.awaitTermination()
```

In the above, i have two kafka topics(test,trial).When i run this program.I can consume the message from trial topic only .Not able to consume message from test topic.

I am not getting any error,the program is running fine . can anyone please help me .

Thanks!

Comment: Did you confirm with the kafka console consumer that test topic is actually streaming?

Comment: yes ,able to read the test topic message through Kafka consumer .

Comment: Code is working as expected. I can only assume there is an issue with your checkpoint files or other infrastructural things. However, running the code as is returns results as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Like Maverik mentioned please make sure all the topics are receiving data. In single stream with multiple topics, the topics are read one by one in sequence.

You may use the below configuration to enable parallelism on the consumer side

```
conf.set("spark.streaming.concurrentJobs", "2");
```

By default the number of concurrent jobs is 1 which means at a time only 1 job will be active and till its not finished,other jobs will be queued up even if the resources are available and idle.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528006/how-jobs-are-assigned-to-executors-in-spark-streaming .

Running concurrent jobs reduces the processing time and scheduling delay even if a batch takes processing time slightly more than batch interval.

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Streaming");
conf.set("spark.streaming.concurrentJobs", "2");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, new Duration(1000));

kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list",
                "broker1:9092,broker2:9092,broker3:9092");
Set<String> topics = Collections.singleton("");

JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, String.class,
                String.class, StringDecoder.class, StringDecoder.class, kafkaParams, topics);
```

Source : http://why-not-learn-something.blogspot.in/2016/06/spark-streaming-performance-tuning-on.html

Comment: Tried setting config("spark.streaming.concurrentJobs", "2"). Not working

Comment: can you try with 4.

Comment: can you get this Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(); and check how many are available?

Comment: You cannot simply increase the number. It totally depends on the number of processors. It is all about scheduling.

Comment: Hi phani , Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() is returning 4 .